# ROC curve vertical average in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, average, roc

Is there a way to compute the vertical average (http://vicos.fri.uni-lj.si/data/vprsistemi/ROCintro.pdf) of several [ROC curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)? I've found in the MATLAB guide that *perfcurve* could do it, but I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just concatenate the probability of detection arrays into a matrix and then take their mean. Assuming your probability of false alarms are held in the row vector `PFA` and your probability of detection values are held in the row vectors `PD1`, `PD2`, ...:

```
PDMatrix = [PD1; PD2; ...];
PDMean = mean(PDMatrix, 1);
```

This assumes your ROC curves all share the same PFA values. If this isn't the case, then you can create a common PFA array and use interp1 to resample your PD arrays before averaging. For example, if you're interested in logarithmically spaced PFA values from 10^-6 to "near 1," and your PFA/PD pairs have the data to interpolate in this range, you can do something like

```
PFAResampled = logspace(-6, -.1, 1000);
PD1Resampled = interp1(PFA1, PD1, PFAResampled);
PD2Resampled = interp1(PFA2, PD2, PFAResampled);
```

After that, you can just concatenate and take the mean as shown above.